# ido-find-file and dropping into directory

Tags: ido-find-file

Reading the documentation for `ido-find-file` it says pressing `C-d` will open the specified directory in dired.

However I can't get this to work no matter what text I leave in the minibuffer, could someone explain how to get this working please?

On Windows x64, Emacs 25.0.50.1

(Update: works on 24.3.1 on BSD)

Comment: Have you tried to reproduce this in `emacs -Q`? What happens if you do `M-x ido-find-file` and then press `C-h k C-d`? (I see "`C-d` runs the command ido-magic-delete-char...", but I'm on a Mac.)

Comment: Hmm no, didn't try -Q.  I'll try on Monday and update, thanks!

Comment: Right, it looks like it only happens when I do `find-file-in-dir` - I sort of expected `C-d` to drop into the directory when I use that, too.